# Help with a regular expression

Tags: c++, regex

I am fairly new to regular expressions and have been having difficulty using one to extract the data I am after. Specifically, I am looking to extract the date touched and the the counter from the following:

```
<span style="color:blue;">&lt;query&gt;</span>
  <span style="color:blue;">&lt;pages&gt;</span>
    <span style="color:blue;">&lt;page pageid=&quot;3420&quot; ns=&quot;0&quot; title=&quot;Test&quot; touched=&quot;2011-07-08T11:00:58Z&quot; lastrevid=&quot;17889&quot; counter=&quot;9&quot; length=&quot;6269&quot; /&gt;</span>
    <span style="color:blue;">&lt;/pages&gt;</span>
  <span style="color:blue;">&lt;/query&gt;</span>
<span style="color:blue;">&lt;/api&gt;</span>
```

I am currently using vs2010. My current expression is:

```
std::tr1::regex rx("(?:.*touch.*;)?([0-9-]+?)(?:T.*count.*;)([0-9]+)(&.*)?");
std::tr1::regex_search(buffer, match, rx);
```

match[1] contains the following:

```
    2011-07-08T11:00:58Z&quot; lastrevid=&quot;17889&quot; counter=&quot;9&quot; length=&quot;6269&quot; /&gt;</span>
    <span style="color:blue;">&lt;/pages&gt;</span>
  <span style="color:blue;">&lt;/query&gt;</span>
<span style="color:blue;">&lt;/api&gt;</span>
```

match[2] contains the following:

```
6269&quot; /&gt;</span>
    <span style="color:blue;">&lt;/pages&gt;</span>
  <span style="color:blue;">&lt;/query&gt;</span>
<span style="color:blue;">&lt;/api&gt;</span>
```

I am looking for just "2011-07-08" in match[1] and just "9" in match[2]. The date format will never alter, but the counter will almost certainly be much larger.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Extracting information out of XML documents is much easier (and more maintainable...) with XPath than with regular expressions.

Comment: @Artanthos: Isn't <span> HTML?


[Regardless, I believe this might apply.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Yes, it is HTML. I am scraping usage data off a website and this is what I have available to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `cmatch::operator[](int i)` returns a `sub_match`, whose `sub_match::operator basic_string()` (used in the context of `cout`) returns a string starting at the beginning of the match and ending at the end of the source string.

Use `sub_match::str()`, i.e. `match[1].str()` and `match[2].str()`.

Moreover, you'll need your expression to be more specific: `.*` tries to match the world, and gives up some if it can't.

Try `std::tr1::regex rx("touched=&quot;([0-9-]+).+counter=&quot;([0-9]+)");`.

You could even use non-greedy matchers (like `+?` and `*?`) to prevent excessive matching.

Comment: Is `*` the non-greedy character in TR1 regex? In most other implementations `?` is used.

Comment: Or maybe you want the super-greedy one (`+`)?

Comment: @Platinum: oh, thanks ! I guess I could invoke the brain fart excuse.

Comment: Thank you. `match[2]` now returns a string starting with the "9". While not ideal, I can just cut `match[1]` and `match[2]` down with a something like `scanf(match[2].first, "%d", &count");`

Comment: @Artanthos: the matcher will not do type conversions for you indeed. You could use `istringstream`, which is less error-prone. If you really want to use `scanf` - or `atoi`, make sure you get a string pointer out of the match (say, you could use `match[2].str().c_str()`).

Comment: @RaphaelSP: No worries, happens to the best of us!

Comment: @Artanthos: oh, by the way, if you think my answer does fulfill your needs, it would be very stackoverflowish of you to accept it :) (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: 'match[2].first' gives the same data conversion as `match[2].str().c_str()`

Comment: @Arthanthos: Ah, indeed. The submatch contains `const char *`'s and not fancy iterators. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
std::tr1::regex rx("(?:.*touch.*;)?([0-9-]+)(?:T.*count.*;)([0-9]+)(&.*)?");
```

removing the question mark makes the term greedy, so it will fill as much as it can.